# dynamically skip top blank rows of excel in python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am reading multiple sheets of an excel file using pandas in python.
I have three cases

1. some sheet has data from row 1

> ```
> osht=pd.DataFrame(filename+sheetname)
>
> delimited table Example: 
> Country;Company;Product
> US;ABC;XYZ
> US;ABD;XYY
> ```

2. and some has n number of blank rows before table and some sheet has summary of 
     I know using skip_blank I can get rid of top blank rows but number of top blank rows are not fixed in nature may be 3 or 4 or 8

> ```
> delimited table Example: 
> ;;
> ;;
> ;;
> Country;Company;Product
> US;ABC;XYZ
> US;ABD;XYY
> ```

3. table in 1st column I am trying to read all these sheet but not sure how 
   -Is there any way to figure out that from 3rd rows summary ends and 4th row is my table heading and first column head is 'Country'

> ```
> delimited table Example: 
>
> Product summary table for East region;;
> Date: 1st Sep, 2016;;
> ;;
> Country;Company;Product
> US;ABC;XYZ
> US;ABD;XYY
> ```

Comment: Have you considered re-conditioning your excel workbook? Load it using python modules for working with excel, eliminate blank rows that you find, and write it back out to the same of a new excel workbook using the excel module for writing excel workbooks. I believe this is your best bet.

Comment: If you provided an example of your data, the question would be improved. How does the summary look like? How many columns and rows does it take? How does one tell summary from column heads?

Comment: how about dropping all blank rows `df.dropna()`

Comment: Thanks, @djk47463 for input but, if I load all data with top blank rows and used dropna() then is there any way to assign actual headers to data back ? and I needed generic script which will work on all three scenarios

Comment: @DavidDale I have provided example tables

Comment: @ThomIves can you provide some example for rewriting excel ? also would it cost decrease in performance as files size is around 60MB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would propose the following algorithm:

1. Read the whole table
2. Consider the first row that contains no missing values as a header
3. Drop all the rows above the header

This code works okay for me:

```
import pandas as pd
for sheet in range(3):
    raw_data = pd.read_excel('blank_rows.xlsx', sheetname=sheet, header=None)
    print(raw_data)
    # looking for the header row
    for i, row in raw_data.iterrows():
        if row.notnull().all():
            data = raw_data.iloc[(i+1):].reset_index(drop=True)
            data.columns = list(raw_data.iloc[i])
            break
    # transforming columns to numeric where possible
    for c in data.columns:
        data[c] = pd.to_numeric(data[c], errors='ignore')
    print(data)
```

It uses [this toy data sample](https://yadi.sk/i/SbLjenLt3PJTGz), based on your examples. From the raw dataframes

```
         0        1        2
0  Country  Company  Product
1       US      ABC      XYZ
2       US      ABD      XYY

         0        1        2
0      NaN      NaN      NaN
1      NaN      NaN      NaN
2      NaN      NaN      NaN
3  Country  Company  Product
4       US      ABC      XYZ
5       US      ABD      XYY

                                       0        1        2
0  Product summary table for East region      NaN      NaN
1                    Date: 1st Sep, 2016      NaN      NaN
2                                    NaN      NaN      NaN
3                                Country  Company  Product
4                                     US      ABC      XYZ
5                                     US      ABD      XYY
```

the script produces the same table

```
  Country Company Product
0      US     ABC     XYZ
1      US     ABD     XYY
```

Comment: Thanks @David,  Great solution.

Comment: Thanks @David,  Great solution. its reading file headings accurate but some how my previous code is not working after attaching above code, after reading data its deleting some columns from data frame based on data types like I am preserving numeric columns and below line is not identifying numeric columns it gives false to numeric columns as well `[head for head in df.columns.tolist() if head not in custom_col_list and not np.issubdtype(df[head].dtype, np.number) ]`

Comment: @RajeshMhatre, you can loop over columns and attempt to convert each to numeric, if that's possible. I added this to my answer.