# pandas read excel sheet with multiple sheets and different header offsets

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have to read an Excel sheet in pandas which contains multiple sheets.
Unfortunately, the number of white space rows before the header starts seems to be different:

```
pd.read_excel('foo.xlsx', header=[2,3], sheet_name='first')
pd.read_excel('foo.xlsx', header=[1,2], sheet_name='second')
```

Is there an elegant way to fix this and read the Excel into a pandas.Dataframe with an additional column which contains the name of each sheet?

I.e. how can

```
pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=None)
```

be passed a varying header argument or choose at least the 2 first (non empty) rows as header?

## edit

[dynamically skip top blank rows of excel in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039309/dynamically-skip-top-blank-rows-of-excel-in-python-pandas?rq=1)
seems to be related but not the solution as only the first headers are accepted.

### edit2

Description of exact file structure:

```
... (varying number of empty rows)
__irrelevant_row__
HEADER_1
HEADER_2
```

where currently it is either 1 or 0 empty rows. But as pointed out in the comment it would be great if that would be more dynamic.

Comment: Interesting. So the `DataFrame` constructor needs to assess at each sheet whether the current set of column names is sufficient, or it needs to expand? In that case it might be worthwhile to first loop over the sheets (could be done using parts of the linked question) to find the `set` of headers; before reading in the actual data.

Comment: At least for my current data it turns out that there are only the two variants of header: `(1,2), (2,3)`. However, ideally this would be recognised dynamically.

Comment: Could you perchance add a mini-example (something like 2 sheets with arbitrary headers and minimal amount of data) to create a reproducible test, where we can assess/discuss the intermediate results as well?

Comment: Certainly, https://github.com/geoHeil/pandas-dynamic-header-from-excel/blob/master/example.xlsx?raw=true is an sample Excel

Comment: Ok. can you try the following: `import openpyxl; book=openpyxl.load_workbook(PATH_TO_FILE); for sh in book.sheetnames: a = pd.DataFrame(book[sh].values).dropna().reset_index(drop=True); print(a)` ? Apologies for the chain code, but as it's not an answer yet, can't do it outside the comment box..

Comment: Your result is not correct. https://imgur.com/a/Ss9jMTX is missing the right columns. Unfortunately, for my real data it fails to work completely - for the sample data it looks rather good. The reason is your call to dropNA which removes any record with any null value. However, it is legitimate for the real file to also contain NULL values in the excel sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am certain this could be done in a more neat fashion, but a way to achieve (I think) what you want is:

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(PATH_TO_FILE)
for sh in book.sheetnames:
    a = pd.DataFrame(book[sh].values).dropna(how='all').reset_index(drop=True)
    a.columns = a.iloc[1]
    a = a.iloc[2:]
    a.iloc[0].index.name=sh
    a["sheet"] = a.iloc[0].index.name
    try:
        b = b.append(a)
    except NameError:
        b = a.copy()
b.iloc[0].index.name = ''
print(b)
#  header1 header2   sheet
#2       1       2   first
#3       3       4   first
#2       1       2  second
#3       3       4  second
#2       1       2     3rd
#3       3       4     3rd
```

Unfortunately I have no clue how it interacts with your actual data, but I do hope this helps you in your quest.

Comment: Indeed, this works for the sample file. Do you see an option wo work also for the real file, i.e. for a file which contains NULL values in the data rows? Your method is currently deleting all the data rows which contain at least a single null value.

Comment: Using `how='all'` will only filter completely empty rows so this is a step better. But I need to also fix the multi index. I.e. there are 2 rows of header in the real data.

Comment: That is a nice addition. Then you can manually delete the first row which you wanted to skip. In other words: `a.columns = a.iloc[1:]; a = a.iloc[2:]` in the loop