# pd.read_excel not always reads all columns

Tags: python, pandas

The task is to read the first five columns of excel into a dataframe:

```
def cqtreader(spec_path, sheet):
    data = pd.read_excel(spec_path, sheet_name=sheet, header=None, usecols='A:F')
```

Sometimes there is some unnecessary data in the rows before. And it changes the behaviour of pd.read_excel.

**Case 1:** pandas reads 4 columns instead of 5
[image]
[image]

**Case 2:** first empty row is removed and pandas reads all 5 columns:
[image]
[image]

**Case 3:** the string 'VMS' is removed form the cell D2 and pandas reads all 5 columns:
[image]
[image]

How to make pandas always read 5 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to write a comment but probably your question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47053634/6687247)